# Retrieve new Firebase data - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, xcode7, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase data]

I'm new to iOS programming. In my project, I have stored the data into the firebase database. I have to retrieve the data for all the "meanACC" values and store it into an array so that the value of that array would be [2,5,6,6]. Please help.

Comment: why exactly do you need this information? could you explain a little more?

Comment: Consider four objects each having some value for "meanAcc" and "peakAcc" stored in the database. Using the app, i want to store the 5th object and want to compare the value of its "meanAcc" with the "meanAcc" values of the four objects already stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current structure you should be doing this loading all the data and iterating over the children to compare each one of the `meanAcc`.

```
ref.child("Data").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in 
    if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for child in result {
            //do your logic and validation here
            child.value["meanAcc"] as! String
        }
    } else {
        print("no results")
    }
}) { (error) in
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Another option is to, whenever storing a new value under `/Data`, store the `meanAcc` value inside another branch `MeanAccs`. And here I'm assuming that the rest of your data is not relevant for your validations.

```
/MeanAccs
    /meanAccValue1 : true
    /meanAccValue2 : true
```

With this structure you can have an array of all the `meanAcc` without having to load the additional information under `Data`.

```
ref.child("MeanAccs").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in 
    if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for child in result {
            var meanAcc = child.key as! String
            print(meanAcc)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a standard query and add the values to an array?

```
    var myArray = [Int]()

    let dataRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("Data")

    dataRef.queryOrderedByChild("meanAcc").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let val = child.value["meanAcc"] as! Int
            myArray.append(val)
        }
        print(myArray) //prints the array [2, 5, 6, 6]
    })
```